# How to dealloc an UIView with MKMapView when I load another UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, core-location, crash-reports

I'm doing an App with a `MKMapView` that has a `back button` the `UIView` which contain the `MKMapView` in order to go to `main menu`, **that's ok**, but when I want to load again the `UIView` with the `MKMapView` my App crash, it doesn't gives any error, just crash and show machine code where it crashed, but it says first: `com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1e5d5220` and then lot of machine code.

The crash report is here:
[image]

I have to add, that the **first time** I load that `UIView` it's **100% working**.

Thanks for your help.

PS: Why I say `dealloc?` because I think doing something like `dealloc` probabbly will fix my problem and will be the same as running the first time.

**EDIT1:**
My `- (void) viewDidLoad;` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *response = [self sendPostToURL: @"http://hidden.php"
                                withPost: @"hidden"];
[self tratarXML: response];
yo = @"Posición actual";
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[self.mapView setDelegate: self];
[self.mapView setZoomEnabled: NO];
[self.mapView setScrollEnabled: NO];
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode: MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated: NO];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    //[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    self.mapView.userLocation.title = yo;
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Debe activar la localización en esta aplicación para funcionar"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

**EDIT2:**
My back button code:

```
- (IBAction) iniciar: (id)sender
{
if ([iniciar.title isEqualToString:@"Volver"])
{
    menuViewController *obj = [[menuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"menuViewController" bundle:nil withUser:user];
    [self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    // censored
}
```

I'm using simple *.xib navigator, not storyboard, etc...

**EDIT3:**
The menu button that load the `MKMapView UIView`

```
- (IBAction) TEST: (id)sender
{
mapaViewController *obj = [[mapaViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"mapaViewController" bundle: nil withUser: user];
[self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code in `mapsViewController`.

Comment: If the controller with the map view is embedded in a navigation controller, it will be deallocated when you hit the back button (unless you're doing something to keep a strong pointer to it). You can easily test this by implementing dealloc in that controller, and put a log statement into it to see if it's called.

Comment: @Rikkles which code do you need? because it doesn't tell me any number of line, and the first time I use it, it always work, so I'm confused what it's going wrong. @rdelmar I'm not using any strong pointer. The 
**dealloc method is not working**, I just typed `NSLog(@"a");` but what do I have to do there? Because I can't dealloc all variables because ARC should do it. :/

Comment: @rokimoki there are two possibilities 1) your view is over released somehow 2)Some process comes infront while the other process is already going on.

Comment: I have a synchronized POST, (so the thread will wait to complete the post before start with new code) - but I have it in all views and only is not working in the `MKMapView UIView` I don't think it's over released, because it makes no sense and probably an apple bug, but I think the possibility of bug it's my code, BTW the bug code should be in `viewDidLoad` and/or `initWithNibName:` method, right?

Comment: This is all a bunch of guesswork until you post some code showing how you move between your controllers, and what your overall app structure is.

Comment: I posted code, sorry for late.

Comment: I don't think that code is enough. You say you have a back button that goes back to the "main menu". Are you creating this controller (the one with the code above) in main menu? How do you go from main menu to the controller with the map view? Are you in a navigation controller? Have you set an exception breakpoint to see if it will pinpoint the offending line of code?

Comment: @rdelmar @Bhargavi @Rikkles edited, added more code, I'm going to add the code that create the `MKMapView UIView`, I'm just using *.xib files and navigate them through that code.

Comment: I have tested with the simulator iOS 6.1 and it's working 100%, but with the iPad Mini with iOS 6.1.3 of my company is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that are wrong:

1. Your back button code should not call a `presentViewController` but a `dismissViewController`. Right now you are adding view controller after view controller! When you go back you want to instead get rid of your view controller.
2. In the back button code, add `self.locationManager.delegate = nil;`
3. Similarly, in the back button code, add `self.mapView.delegate = nil;`

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't know about `dismissViewController` :/, now I have this code: `if ([iniciar.title isEqualToString:@"Volver"]){ self.locationManager.delegate = nil; [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil]; }` and still crashing....

Comment: I missed another point: setting the mapView delegate to nil. But you also must be doing something else outside the code you pasted that is keeping your view controllers in memory or something like that.

Comment: 1) If I set those variables to nil directly? 2) in simulator is 100% working my code 3) with mapView.delegate to nil it's working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing a series of presentViewController calls to go from main menu to the map view controller, and then back to the main menu. This is not how it should be done. You probably shouldn't be doing modal transitions at all, but if you do, you should have the main menu dismiss the map view controller, not have the map view controller present another main menu controller.

The better way to do this would be with a navigation controller. Main menu should be the root view controller of a navigation controller, and you would push to go to the map view controller. You will automatically get a back button in the navigation bar, which will take you back (to the same instance) of the main menu controller. No need for any back button code. All this would be much easier to implement in a storyboard.

Comment: I'm sure about that, but I don't know how to do (I know I can research the how to but I don't have time, and my company is forcing me to do iOS and don't have too much time to learn and work at the same time with not too much time). In the other hand I'm sending to some views some kind of variables to be used, I know there are statics variables and so, but I don't want to use them, so that's why I'm doing like I'm doing, I appreciate your help, probably I will change my navigation system, sorry for my english.